# Is there a common term to call a given Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I was going through [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/209901) and could not find any term to describe a generic site apart from... *site*.

So if you are in, say, [Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/), how do you refer to the site itself? Is *site* commonly accepted enough to describe this Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Yes. The site or community

Comment: Mmm there is no mention of _site_ in the glossary, Patrick.

Comment: Yes, I had to type faster or close later. Sorry. Nevertheless, the word 'site' is used a lot in the Glossary, so it is clear already. Added it nonetheless.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Refresh the Glossary.

Comment: OK, thanks. So for future readers: @PatrickHofman added the entry _Community_ to the Stack Exchange Glossary.

Comment: Feel free to add something to the glossary if you think that is useful.

Comment: OK :) I may prefer to bring it through a new question so I can be sure there is consensus on the topic. Thanks!